# High Performance Web Application Framework

Tags: android, performance, angularjs, web-applications, sproutcore

I'm trying to build a web app that is as responsive as a native Android App. Is that even possible?

We tried PhoneGap and SproutCore and it is not responsive enough. Are there better alternatives? I mean how does, for example, AngularJs compare to SproutCore in terms of visual and all-around performance?

Comment: The unresponsiveness may be due to browsers waiting for 300ms after a tap-and-release before sending the click event. Angular has ngTouch module which solves this problem. FYI: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngClick

Comment: Agreed with the poster below that getting performance takes some fine-tuning. I'm a SproutCore developer who's got some very responsive apps running in Mobile Safari; what specific responsiveness issues were you having?

Comment: Most of the unresponsiveness is in the animations when loading the different pages and list scrolling. Other than these specifics, it's just got an overall sluggish feel when compared to what you'd expect from a native app

Comment: List scrolling in SproutCore takes some special fu to get as smooth as possible, but it's definitely doable. (Note that this is true natively too; try googling "ios smooth table scrolling".) The secret is removing bindings, and flattening your list's exampleView using the lower-level custom render API. I'd need to know more about the loading pages sluggishness, but if it's when switching parts of the app, make sure you're caching views rather than creating/destroying, and see if you've got an unreasonable number of bindings going on. They're awesome but they're not free! =)

Answer (score 0):

Angular and Topcoat seem to be working pretty good together.  But I think ratchet framework is going to develop into something much better.  It's fast and has lots of mobile like components.
There is also a nice youtube presentation about the possibilities from the first ng-conf, check that out too.

Answer (score 0):

You won't find today an out-of-the-box framework to write HTML/JS mobile applications as fast as native ones. It's possible to obtain very decent performances with webapps, but for this you'll have to do some optimizations by yourself. At least, that's the conclusion I draw after reading [this article from Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/blog/the-making-of-fastbook-an-html5-love-story/) to have an idea about how they wrote a fast facebook mobile app clone, using their Framework.

Angular with some tuning [as described by Scalyr](http://blog.scalyr.com/2013/10/31/angularjs-1200ms-to-35ms/) may be very fast.  Iconics framework could be of some interest for you too, as long as you limit your app to recent OS.

Be aware that performances with Android Dolphin web browser will always be disappointing compared to what you can get on iOS or with Chrome on more recent of Android.